# Case Statement Error at Both End Lines

Tags: t-sql

Im trying to figure out why the second BEGIN/END block errors on the lines 22 and 25. The END for both cases. Did I miss something? Also how could I make this one query instead of two blocks?

```
    BEGIN

     SELECT

     l.partNum AS [Part Number]
    ,l.pricePerUOM AS [Price Per UOM]
    ,l.uom AS [UOM]
    ,SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,12), l.totalCostPerWS/l.pricePerUOM)) AS [Quantity/WS] INTO #temp
   FROM tbl_step s
    JOIN tbl_line l ON s.stepId = l.stepId
    WHERE s.revisionId = @revisionId
            AND ISNUMERIC(l.totalCostPerWS) > 0
            AND ISNUMERIC(l.pricePerUOM) > 0
        GROUP BY l.partNum, l.pricePerUOM, l.uom
    END

    BEGIN
        SELECT
             l.partNum AS [Part Number]
            ,l.pricePerUOM AS [Price Per UOM]
            ,l.uom AS [UOM]
        ,CASE
            WHEN l.partNum >=2 AND l.uom = 'liter' THEN (SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,12),[Quantity/WS] * 1000)
        END AS [Converted]
        ,CASE
            WHEN l.uom = 'milliliter' THEN (SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,12),[Quantity/WS] + l.pricePerUOM)
        END AS [Qnty/WS + Price per UOM]
        FROM #temp
            JOIN tbl_line l ON s.stepId = l.stepId
            JOIN tbl_step s ON l.stepId = s.stepId
            WHERE
                ISNUMERIC(l.totalCostPerWS) > 0
            AND ISNUMERIC(l.pricePerUOM) > 0
        GROUP BY l.partNum, l.pricePerUOM, l.uom
    END
```

Thanks for any help. 
F

Comment: Use the code-button(curly braces) to format your code. More informations: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/147438

Comment: Okay, I strongly recommend that instead of saying "hey, I have this huge query that errors, why?" you should start by showing us the data in your table and the result you want. I am 99% positive that if you start there we can show you a much more efficient way to retrieve the desired results than doing all this #temp table and double-nested query stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You also have this:

```
FROM #temp
JOIN tbl_line l ON s.stepId = l.stepId
JOIN tbl_step s ON l.stepId = s.stepId
```

I think perhaps you meant:

```
FROM #temp AS t
JOIN tbl_line l ON t.stepId = l.stepId
JOIN tbl_step s ON l.stepId = s.stepId
```

However that would require that #temp have a stepId column. I think you need to step back and start with a more simplified query, because a whole bunch of what you're doing now doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry, new to the site. But my top query block works fine, and outputs the data into the temp table.

Comment: So what is the error on the second block? You need to include enough information that people can figure out what's going on. "Broken" doesn't cut it.

Comment: Sorry Aaron, Im trying to add some table data, but adding and formatting is giving me more of a problem than the code itself! :)

Answer (score 0):

Lose the embedded `SELECT`'s:

```
,CASE
WHEN l.partNum >=2 AND l.uom = 'liter' THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,12),[Quantity/WS] * 1000)
END AS [Converted]
,CASE
WHEN l.uom = 'milliliter' THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,12),[Quantity/WS] + l.pricePerUOM)
END AS [Qnty/WS + Price per UOM]
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this worked for you please mark the Accepted checkbox by the answer:)